# What can I do to stop kernel from dying in Spyder with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, spyder

I am running Spyder with Anaconda on Windows 7 64bit and 8GB of RAM. Everything is updated. I am trying to run the following script from a CNN tutorial that tries to classify images of cats and dogs:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import optimizers
from keras import metrics

classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 64, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

my_optimizer = optimizers.Nadam(lr=0.015, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, schedule_decay=0.004)
classifier.compile(optimizer = my_optimizer, loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = [metrics.binary_accuracy])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/training_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=15,
        class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/test_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=15,
        class_mode='binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=800,
        epochs=25,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=200)
```

Everything seems to work fine but when it gets to the last `classifier.fit_generator(...)` command the kernel dies and restarts.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling keras but still the same problem remains. The last thing I see in the console before the kernel dies is:

```
Found 8000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/25
Kernel died, restarting
```

Can you please help me understand where the problem lies and how to solve it? RAM doesn't seem to be an issue as it doesn't even fill up to 100% before the kernel dies.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Does your code work in the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I tried with Jupyter but the result is exactly the same: the kernel dies and I have no report on the kind of error that killed it.

Comment: Then this is not a problem with Spyder. Sorry but I can't help you further because I don't use Tensorflow.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Maybe you are right. I switched to Theano and it seems that the epoch is working fine. I will leave it to train during the night and see how precise it is tomorrow. Maybe I'll try to sort it out why Tensorflow doesn't work.